# Different plot size for plt.show() and fig.savefig()

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, size, font-size

I have to create some plots that I want to integrate into a scientific document. Due to space limitations the size of the plot as well as the font size is rather small.
For debugging/convenience reasons it would be nice to interactively show the plot using `plt.show()` with a larger size for the plot and fonts, before storing it as a PDF file using `fig.savefig(...)` with smaller sizes.

I achieved to set a different plot size before displaying it. However, I was not able to update the font size. Any ideas how this would be possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib as mpl
from pylab import *

params = {
    'text.usetex': True,
    'font.size': 6,
}
mpl.rcParams.update(params)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [2, 2, 2]

ax.plot(x,y, label='label')

plt.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('plot.pdf')

fig.set_size_inches(10, 8, forward=True)
params = {'font.size': 20}
mpl.rcParams.update(params)
plt.show()
```

I am using Matplotlib 2.0.2, but also tried 1.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tangential note: you shouldn't `from pylab import *`, that will clutter your namespace with all sorts of needless things:

```
>>> len(globals())
6
>>> from pylab import *
>>> len(globals())
988
```

As you noticed, I don't think that setting any of the `rc` parameters affects *existing* plots. You might have to get your hands dirty, although only a bit: there is only a handful of children of your `Axes` that you need to modify:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # <-- all you need here

params = {
    'text.usetex': True,
    'font.size': 6,
}
mpl.rcParams.update(params)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [2, 2, 2]

ax.plot(x,y, label='label')

plt.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('plot.pdf')

fig.set_size_inches(10, 8, forward=True)
# v--- change title and axeslabel font sizes manually
for item in ([ax.title, ax.xaxis.label, ax.yaxis.label] +
             ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(20)
plt.show()
```

Saved (left) and shown (right) version:

[image: saved version] [image: shown version]

Arguably, it might be more elegant (or a different kind of messy) to just close your saved plots, modify your `rcParams`, and redraw the versions you want to `show`.

Comment: Thanks! That works as it should and I also appreciate your comment regarding the imports.

Comment: I improved the solution a little bit by also increasing the font size for the legend: `for text in ax.get_legend().get_texts():
                text.set_fontsize(_displayFontSize)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't want to change anything in the plot if showing it on a larger scale is for debugging or magnifying reasons. That's why you may not want to change any of the rc paramters, nor would you want to change the figure size.

Instead you'd just prepare the figure the way it should be saved for your publication and after saving, **change its dpi** (dots per inch), `fig.set_dpi(xxx)`.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

params = {
    'text.usetex': True,
    'font.size': 6,
}
plt.rcParams.update(params)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [2, 2, 2]

ax.plot(x,y, label='label')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('plot.pdf')

fig.set_dpi(300)

plt.show()
```

saved figure:
[image]

shown figure (with 300 dpi):

[image]